# Django Streaming DumpData

Tags: python, database, django

How do you get Django's dumpdata management command to stream contents to a file instead of loading everything into memory?

I'm trying to convert a 1GB Sqlite3 database to PostgreSQL, and one method I'm considering is dumping the database to json using `python manage.py dumpdata --all --format=json > mydatabase.json`.

This ran for about 5 minutes before it consumed all my memory and crashed my machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try a patch from https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5423, but I think a better way is to dump data to sql.

Comment: This issue has been known for 4 years...and a patch as been available all that time?! Sigh...

Comment: I think there are valid reasons for this (discussion in ticket comments is helpful), and it's for good the patch was not merged; the issue is not only with django itself but with database drivers as well, and there are other means for migrating the database from one engine to another anyway.

Comment: No good means. Dumpdata provides a relatively clean and simple way to migrate filtered data between any engine supported by Django's ORM. Sure, I could use the tools specific to each SQL backend to dump and load my data, but that gets much more complicated, and requires that I know all the nuances to each particular backend...which shouldn't be necessary.